# Floor trim / Scotia between tiles and vinyl floor

Tags: bathroom, trim, vinyl-flooring

I'm replacing carpet in a small bathroom with vinyl. **I'm wondering what the best way to seal the vinyl against the wall edge would be?** I've seen different approaches, some suggesting just using a standard floor trim/Scotia to allow for expansion/contraction. Another method was simply using a thin silicon seal.

The walls are tiled down to the floor so I need to take that into consideration (does this affect which adhesive to use?) - I'm not sure if it matters but I'll be using a hardboard layer under the vinyl for better levelling.

All advice welcome and very helpful!

Comment: What did you end up doing? Please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you cannot effectively tuck the glued vinyl under the wall tile, I think a "scotia" style trim would be most effective over time. It has been my experience that the vinyl will pull up along the edge if simply glued and "ended" at the wall, even if you use a "thin silicone seal".

If you could find a trim piece that would accomodate the thickness of your hardboard underlayment *and* the vinyl layer, so that both would be secured in "dimension D" in the picture below, that would work the best IMO:

[image]

picture stolen shamelessly from the internet

Comment: I think a trim will work best too - is it worth sealing the actual trim along the top against the tiles? Also, what's the long blue line tucking under 'D' there? Surely not part of the trim itself?